# Can this be done with regex?

Tags: regex

I have a string with different length sub-strings split by symbol '_' and some sub-strings have to be split in multiple sub-sub-strings...

Example:

```
"_foo-2_bar-12_un[3;1]iver[3]se[3-7]"
```

should be split in groups like this:

```
"foo-2", "2", "bar-12", "12", "un[3;1]", "3;1", "iv", "er[3]", "3", "se[3-7]", "3-7"
```

I've come up with something like this:

```
/(?:((?:(?:\[([a-z0-9;-]+)\])|(?<=_)(?:[a-z0-9]+)|-([0-9]+))+))/ig
```

The problem I encounter is with the last part. And after finicking around I started to think whether or not this is even possible. Is it?

Any kind of a guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Like this: [`([^\W_]+(?|\[([^][]*)]|-([^_]+)))`](https://regex101.com/r/sA2xC7/2)? The captured values will give you expected `[foo-2, 2, bar-12, 12, un[3;1], 3;1, iver[3], 3, se[3-7], 3-7]`. What is your regex flavor?

Comment: Not quite, it doesn't split the last part separately and doesn't include squire brackets in the group. (but still, better than mine)
The regex flavor is ECMA-262

Comment: It does, see [`([^\W_]+(?:\[([^\][]*)]|-([^_]+)))`](https://regex101.com/r/sA2xC7/3). ECMA-262 means a JS flavor, so you need to use a non-capturing group instead of a branch reset and then check which group matched. Are you looking for a JS solution?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a JS solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
/[^\W_]+(?:\[([^\][]*)]|-([^_]+))/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nR6sO9/1)

The pattern matches any 1+ char alphanumeric sequence (`[^\W_]+`) followed either with `[...]` substrings having no `[` and `]` inside (with `\[([^\][]*)]` - note it captures what is inside `[...]` into Group 1) OR a hyphen followed with 1+ characters other than `_` (and this part after `-` is captured into Group 2).

```js
var re = /[^\W_]+(?:\[([^\][]*)]|-([^_]+))/g; 
var str = '_foo-2_bar-12_un[3;1]iver[3]se[3-7]';
var res = [];
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
   res.push(m[0]);
   if (m[1]) {
     res.push(m[1]);
   } else {
     res.push(m[2]);
   }
}

document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```

In this code, the match object is analyzed at each iteration: the 0th group (the whole match) ias added to the final array, and then if Group 1 matched, Group 1 is added, else, Group 2 is added to the resulting array.